# Problems with add_tooltip from ggvis with R Shiny

Tags: r, tooltip, shiny, scatter-plot, ggvis

I have looked all over for an answer, but none of them solve the problem I am having. I am creating an R Shiny application with a number of graphics. One is an interactive scatter plot where the user can hover over points and information pops up. The scatter plot DOES appear, but I cannot get the ggvis tooltip information to pop, and I get NO errors. It just seems to ignore the html part of add_tooltip.

UI:

```
shinyUI(fluidPage( theme = "bootstrap.css",
    tabPanel("Interactive ScatterPlot",
                  #uiOutput("ggvis_ui"), #have tried with and without this
                  ggvisOutput("scatter_plot")
                )
             )
         )
```

Server:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

tooltipValues <- function(x) {
print(1) #doesn't print
if(is.null(x)) return(NULL)
print(x) #doesn't print
row <- out[out$id==x$id,]
paste0("Row: ", row$rowNames, "<br>Column: ", row$colNames)
}

scatter <- reactive({

indices1 <- tempJaccard() #this works
out <- scatterPlotDF(indices1) #scatterPlotDF is working, out is a dataframe

out %>% 
ggvis(x=~rowP, y=~colP, fill=~rowNames) %>% 
layer_points(size := 50, size.hover:=200, key:=~id) %>% #the points do magnify on hover
add_axis("x",title="Budget Description Percentile") %>%
add_axis("y",title="OV-5a Percentile") %>%
add_tooltip(tooltipValues,"hover")   
}) 

scatter %>% bind_shiny("scatter_plot") #I've tried different versions of this line
#end server
)}
```

My scatterplot and tooltip work when I run it in the command console but not in my full application (both in R Studio and in Chrome). I have already looked at stackoverflow questions 24519980 and 24959609 as well as:

http://rpackages.ianhowson.com/cran/ggvis/man/add_tooltip.html

I want something like this:

http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/movie-explorer.html

The source code is on github.

Comment: So I finally got figured out a solution but I'm not sure what the exact problem was. There was something wrong with the dataframe I was getting back from scatterPlotDF. When I printed it off it was fine, but ggvis couldn't properly handle it. I fixed this by sending back a matrix and converting that to a dataframe. In addition, ggvis does not know the names of every column in your dataframe, it only knows the ones you have used as parameters to ggvis functions (which is very strange/annoying/not defined anywhere).

Comment: Because you used a `key` you can pull out whatever columns in the dataset you want and put them in your tooltip, it just depends on what you put in the function.